# How could users in Backup Operators group escalate its privileges?

Tags: windows

If I'm in the `Backup Operators` group, is it possible for me to escalate the privilege to Administrators?

I'm talking about both Domain computers and non-Domain computers.

P.S I've tried to do `net user whatever /ad` and I got access denied error, not sure whether `Backup Operators` users can do bad things

Comment: There's many many many many ways to escalate privileges. It's highly dependent on what's installed, how it's configured, who the user is and what their permissions are. This is a good guide https://blog.g0tmi1k.com/2011/08/basic-linux-privilege-escalation/

Answer (score 1):

> So to resume your query, you want to know if the **Backup Operators** group
>   (local and domain) can escalate privileges to the **Administrators** group. Based on my research ([source](https://www.cert-ist.com/pub/files/Forum2016-04-LE_TOUX-First_active_directory_v2.3.pdf)) and after reproducing the steps bellow in my lab (2012 R2), my answer is **YES**.

Steps:

1. Ensure to be member of the **Backup Operators** group
2. Open an interactive session on a domain controller. If server is not virtual, physical access to the rack will be required. If server is virtual, proper access to the virtualization control center (like *VMware vCenter*) will be required
3. Once logged in, dig into C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain\Policies{xxx}\MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\ folder and look for a file named "GptTmpl.inf" which looks like the following image:

[image: backup operator GPO]

4. Make a copy of this file and add the SID of the desired account as shown below. To obtain the SID of an account by PowerShell, use the following command : *[wmi] "win32_userAccount.Domain='',Name=''"*

[image: modified sid gpo]

5. Backup the file
6. Restore the file and redirect it to the real SYSVOL location, overwriting the existing GPO
7. Wait for GPO to refresh or force GPO refresh (gpupdate /force)

> For your information, a member of the Backup operators group can:
>    - Can back up and restore files regardless of the permissions that protect those files
>
> - Can back up system state
> - Can interactively logon (RDP excluded) on all servers (including DC)
> - Can logon to shutdown a server